# What are the difference between flex application life cycle and component life cycle?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flash-builder

What are the difference between flex 4 application life cycle and component life cycle ?
Are these are same in terms of steps ?

Answer (score 0):

A component is only a UIComponent. It lives various phase depending on it's state. An Application (spark or halo) is an Application and, in addition to the life cycle, bootstraps itself ...